# What is difference between Bayesian Networks and Belief Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, probability, bayesian-networks, difference

While reading some articles about Bayesian Networks, I came across many occurrences of Belief Networks.

Do both of these terms mean the same thing or is there any difference between Bayesian Networks and Belief Networks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are literally the same. A Belief network is the one, where we establish a **belief** that certain event A will occur, given B. The network assumes the structure of a directed graph. The term **Bayesian** was coined after the name of Thomas Bayes.