# What's the difference between probabilistic programming such as pyro and belief networks?

Tags: deep-learning, bayesian-networks, probabilistic-programming

I heard about ubers pyro and stumbled upon [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_belief_network) Wikipedia article.

As I understand, a bayesian network is the same as a belief network according to [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/what-is-difference-between-bayesian-network-and-belief-network) post.

Does someone know how these are related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A probabilistic program and a Bayesian Network are both ways of specifying probabilistic models. Any model that can be specified as a Bayesian Network can also be specified by a probabilistic program, in fact by a probabilistic program that has no control flow. Roughly

```
Bayes Nets == Straight line Probabilistic Programs
```

For example consider the Bayes Net[image]

This Bayes Net is equivalent to the probabilistic program (in Pyro)

```py
def model():
    p_rain = pyro.param("p_rain", torch.tensor(0.2), constraint=unit_interval)
    p_sprinkler = pyro.param("p_sprinkler", torch.tensor([0.4, 0.01]),
                             constraint=unit_interval)
    p_wet = pyro.param("p_wet", torch.tensor([[0.0, 0.9], [0.8, 0.99]]),
                       constraint=unit_interval)

    rain = pyro.sample("rain", Bernoulli(p_rain))
    sprinkler = pyro.sample("sprinkler",
                            Bernoulli(p_sprinkler[rain.long()]))
    wet = pyro.sample("wet", Bernoulli(p_wet[rain.long(), sprinkler.long()]))
```

More generally, probabilistic programs can contain control flow (`if`, `for`, `while`) and recursion. Some of these extra features are expressed in extensions to Bayes nets, e.g. some `for` loops can be expressed as *plates* in Bayes Nets.

Comment: What's the point of `p_rain`? It's never used. Should it be removed, since `rain` defined further down seems to be the important version.