# Bayes net inference in Pyro

Tags: bayesian-networks, probabilistic-programming

I am familiar with Bayes nets (discrete/continuous/hybrid). I recently started to learn basics of Pyro and tried to model simple Bayes nets as Pyro programs. I also noticed the simple example answered in Question "[Whats the Difference between probabilistic programming such as pyro and Belief networks?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42458/)".

Can anyone provide a full working Pyro example that shows Bayesian **inference** for computing any node/variable X posterior distribution **P**(X|**e**) in a Bayes net given some set of evidence **e**? Inference can be exact or approximate. The 3-node example from the mentioned answer would suffice.

Comment: There is a related question in the Pyro forum:
https://forum.pyro.ai/t/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-bayesian-network-with-pyro/421

Comment: Have you followed the pyro tutorial? This is discussed pretty early on: http://pyro.ai/examples/intro_part_ii.html#Conditioning